# How do we get Near By Places from Google Places API in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

Research how to configure Google Places API key for the Android app, given the API restrictions limit us based on referring website.
Now Google consider Place API as Web-service so it is compulsory to restrict API key with IP address. So i got null result in android code and it says that "API key not restricted" so now how to use API key in Android App for getting near by places result.

Answer (score 2):

Please see https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/get-api-key#restrict-key for instructions to restrict your API key for use with your Android app.

To achieve displaying nearby places using the Places SDK for Android, you have two options:

1. Use [`PlacesClient.findCurrentPlace()`](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/current-place) to get the most likely places immediately around the device's current location.
2. Use [Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete) with either [`setLocationBias` or `setLocationRestriction`](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#constrain_autocomplete_results) to allow the user to type a particular place name or query that they would like to search for around a specific location.

Comment: I tried PlacesClient.findCurrentPlace() using Places SDK for Android, but I am not able to use restricted API key (package name & SHA1). I am getting an error but I can ideally use it as its not simple API call but its SDK for android. Any help would be highly appreciated.